# ggplot2 - 2 variable clustered column chart - gradient fill for variable 1 and solid fill for variable 2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the below data that I would like to create a clustered column chart from. Note this is dummy data.

```
dataraw <- read.table(
  text = "CRITERIA,ACTUAL,FUTURE,EFFORT
  Crit1,2,4,2
  Crit2,3,4,3
  Crit3,1,4,5",
  header = T, sep = ","
)
```

I wish to use ACTUAL and FUTURE as my two columns and CRITERIA as my x axis.

For context, ACTUAL is a measure where the criteria is currently sitting. Whereas FUTURE is the ideal state of where the criteria should be. EFFORT is a measure of how much effort it would take to get from ACTUAL to FUTURE.

The complexity is that I wish to use EFFORT as the gradient fill (ideally customization available - eg blue low, red high) for ACTUAL only and I need FUTURE to be a solid colour of my choosing (at this point black, however it may be adjusted).

Currently I am able to plot the chart with the fill, but I am not sure how to include the FUTURE column.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dataraw, aes(x = CRITERIA, y = ACTUAL, fill = EFFORT)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Which results in the following output:

[image: Which results in the following output.]

Alternatively I can melt the data as so and plot the output, however EFFORT becomes a measure just the same as ACTUAL & FUTURE.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

dataraw.m <- melt(dataraw, id.vars="CRITERIA")

ggplot(data = dataraw.m, aes(CRITERIA, value)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), width = 0.4,
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), stat = "identity")
```

Which results in this output:

[image: Which results in this output.]

I could remove EFFORT from the dataframe however that would remove my ability to create the gradient in ACTUAL.

I'm still quite new to R, so I am not certain if what I am asking is even possible.

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Comment: does this look like what you are thinking? `ggplot(dataraw, aes(x = CRITERIA, y = ACTUAL, fill = EFFORT)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") + 
  geom_col(aes(y = FUTURE), fill = "black") +
  geom_col()`

Comment: @Nate far better than my answer.

Comment: thanks, but not sure what OP wants, they might want the side by side like you built it, you never know

Comment: @Nate very, very close thank you. The only adjustment I need is for the columns to be side by side, rather than ACTUAL sitting on top of FUTURE. Are there any arguments to make them side by side?

Comment: Sorry Nate & Tjebo to clarify, Crit1 would ideally have ACTUAL and FUTURE together. Then following this Crit2, then Crit3. Trejbo your solution is also very close however ACTUAL and FUTURE are separated, rather than Crit1 having both ACTUAL and FUTURE side by side - if that makes sense?

Comment: in `geom_col`, use `position = position_nudge()` and play with the `x` argument. You might want to play with the `width` argument in `geom_col` too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full warning this is starting to get a little hacky, but here we go:

```
ggplot(dataraw, aes(x = CRITERIA, y = ACTUAL, fill = EFFORT)) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "blue", high = "red") + 
  geom_col(aes(y = FUTURE), fill = "black", width = .4, position = position_nudge(.2)) +
  geom_col(width = .4, position = position_nudge(-.2))
```

[image]

The only tricks are that `width` is best if less than .5 and that `position_nudge` is 1/2 whatever the `width` value is.

FYI `geom_col()` is equivalent to `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty approach: Plot several times. Make your data long (I use `tidyr::gather`), so that you can use the values on the same y-axis. Then define the color for `future` outside of `aes`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

dataraw <- structure(list(CRITERIA = c("Crit1", "Crit2", "Crit3"), ACTUAL = c(2L, 3L, 1L), FUTURE = c(4L, 4L, 4L), EFFORT = c(2L, 3L, 5L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 3L))

data_long <- dataraw %>% gather(time, value, ACTUAL, FUTURE)

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = filter(data_long, time == 'ACTUAL'),
           mapping = aes(x = time, y = value, group = CRITERIA, fill = EFFORT), 
           stat = 'identity',
           position = position_dodge(width = 1.01))+
geom_bar(data = filter(data_long, time == 'FUTURE'),
         mapping = aes(x = time, y = value, group = CRITERIA),
         fill = c('black', 'white', 'grey'),
         stat = 'identity',
         position = position_dodge(width = 1.01))
```

[image]

This doesn't look exactly "nice" and you can probably play around with the dodge-width, and of course the colors. 
Maybe you might want to consider plotting differently. Maybe the 'future' column behind the actual column.

Created on 2018-12-21 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Many thanks Tjebo. Quite close but not quite it. I have learned a little bit more about R by reviewing your solution however so I am very appreciative. Many thanks and regards.

Comment: @JosephJW no probs. it might become mildly trickier when you want to add “future” to the legend, but it’s possible. there are some threads on how to use several aesthetics in legends. if you want that and run into problems, let us know.